# Replacing what's in a string with what's in an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am making a filter for strings that will filter out any words in the string that are found in the array with the number sign "#". It just doesn't seem to work.

Here are my url parameters:
http://www.mydomain.com/test.php?str=Noob%20no

```
<?php
    $blacklist = array("noob","yes");
    $t = "";
    $str = explode(" ",strtolower($_GET["str"]));
    foreach ($str as $i) {
        $s = str_replace($i, str_repeat("#", strlen($i)), $blacklist);
        $t = $t . $s[0];
    }

    echo $t;
?>
```

This is what it outputs for "noob no:"

> ######ob

where it should echo something like this:

> #### no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$blacklist = array("noob","yes");
$t = "";
$str = explode(" ",strtolower("Noob no"));
foreach ($str as $i) {
    if ( in_array($i,$blacklist) ) {
       $i = str_repeat('#',strlen($i));
    }
    $t = $t . $i . " ";
}

echo $t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$blacklist = array("noob","yes");

$words = explode(" ", $_GET["str"]);
foreach($words as &$word) {
    if(in_array(strtolower($word), $blacklist)) {
        $word = str_repeat("#", strlen($word));
    }
}

echo implode(' ', $words);
```

Your fundamental issue was with how you used [`str_repeat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php), but I cleaned this up a bit.  I pass the array of words [by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), and then if the word (here is where we strtolower, thanks @Thomas) is part of the blacklist we will replace `$word` with `#`s.  Finally, we will [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to get our final string.

Final example: [IDE One](http://ideone.com/Ef9XXR).

Comment: Only thing to make this better would be to strtolower the word so as to keep the original data? if(in_array(strtolower($word), $blacklist)) and $words = explode(" ", $_GET["str"]);

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of using in_array...feel kinda stupid now haha.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function right.

Try this:

```
$blacklist = array("noob", "yes");
$t = "";
$str = explode(" ", strtolower($_GET["str"]));
foreach ($str as $word) {
    $s = in_array($word, $blacklist)? str_repeat("#", strlen($word)): $word;
    $t = $t . " " . $s;
}

echo $t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
    $blacklist = array("noob","yes");
    $t = "";
    $str = explode(" ",strtolower($_GET["str"]));
    foreach ($str as $i) {
        if (in_array($i, $blacklist))
            $i = str_replace($i, str_repeat("#", strlen($i)), $i);
        $t .= $i." ";
    }
    echo trim($t);
?>
```